# How to fix character encoding with é read from csv file

Tags: php, encoding

In php I read a file (`.csv`) when the file is read all the accent if screw up... but let's talk about the `é` ONLY here...

In the file, the `é` is seen correctly (open in text edit on mac os x). Then the file is uploaded to a server and read with PHP, then it's echoed out...

The problem appears NEVER ever the `é` with the accent show up to the screen

When I have done a `ord($str[1])` to "view" the character it's `142`, so it's `#008E`

What can I do to convert this character to the proper `é` and view it... `utf8_decode` doesn't work! The `é` (`#008e`) become `00c2` NOT `é`

Comment: First, the obvious: Check that the culprit is not the server itself. Some servers convert text files to pure ASCII when uploaded. Try downloading the text file from the server to your machine and open it. See if it's still showing the accent.

Comment: Also, what encoding are you using that renders 142 (#008e) to é? In Unicode, it's supposed to be 233 (#00e9)...

Comment: the whole problem is there, it's supposed to be, but it's not... i think i can guess that macintosh encoding is the one... so the question how to convert macintosh to utf8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix my problem like that :

```
$file = "detaillants.csv";
$read_file = file($file); //read file into array of string
$read_file_encoded = utf8_encode_array($read_file); // encode array en UTF8
$read_file_map = array_map('str_getcsv', $read_file_encoded); // multidimension array 12 item each
```

and use this code to write data into WP DB

```
foreach ($values as $value) {

    $post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'detaillants',
        'post_title' => $value["nom"]
        ) );

    update_post_meta($post_id,'wpcf-adresse',$value["adresse"]);
    update_post_meta($post_id,'wpcf-latitude',$value["latitude"]);
    update_post_meta($post_id,'wpcf-longitude',$value["longitude"]);

    }
```